# Twitter bootstrap compare password validation

Tags: jquery, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have done a basic form using twitter bootstrap . I was able to perform some validation also.

```
<form class="form-signin">            
<input type="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" required="">
<input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required="">
<input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" required="">
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

In numerous examples  i searched , nobody has used compare password validation.
I was wondering if there is a compare password validation in twitter bootstrap other than using j query validator ?
Can compare password validation be performed by using css and not by using form.validate() script?

Thanks

Comment: please note that you just need `required` not `required=""`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thnx dude .

Comment: @Ohgodwhy can u help me on compare password validation?

Answer (score 4):

You can't `validate a form` using `css`, if you don't want `jquery validate plugin` then you can try it like,

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
   if($('#pass').val()!=$('#cpass').val()){
       alert('Password not matches');
       return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-signin">
    <input type="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" required="">
    <input id="pass" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <input id="cpass" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" required="">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required="" id="psd">
<input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" required="" id="confirmPsd">
```

I've added `id` for more convenient.

**JS:**

```
$('button').on ('click', function () {
if ($('#confirmPsd').val() === $('#psd').val()) {
  alert("Equal");
  return true;
}
else {
  alert("don't matches");
 return false;
}
})
```

Comment: `$('#confirmPsd')` is missing a `#`